# How can I run a Job only when on a Cellular Network using WorkManager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I'm developing an application that has to run a job when WiFi connection is lost. I can easily detect when the device gets WiFi connection by using WorkManager, but I haven't found a way to set a Worker to only run on Cellular data, which I would set immediately after detecting the user has connected to a WiFi network.

The way I used to do it was using BroadcastReceivers which would let me know when the user connected or disconnected from a WiFi network.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<receiver android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Unfortunately in API 28 SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION has been deprecated.

Thankfully though, in API 28 I can now use JobScheduler to achieve a similar effect setting up the job like this:

```
val jobBuilder = JobInfo.Builder(jobId, ComponentName(context, NetworkService::class.java))
val requiredNetwork = NetworkRequest.Builder().addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR).build()
jobBuilder.setRequiredNetwork(requiredNetwork)
```

I know I can combine the two solutions and use one or the other according to the device API, but I would like to avoid it. I've looked at WorkManager, but have not found a way to run a Worker only when on Cellular data. Am I missing something or is this currently not possible with WorkManagers?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** If you can assume that the cellular network is always metered and the WiFi is always unmetered, you can use those NetworkTypes as constraints. See comments for more details, as it seems that this is not always the case.

**Original answer**

You can create a new WorkRequest with a [`Network.METERED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/NetworkType.html#METERED) constraints in the Work that is run when there's a WIFI connecction.

This new work will be run when the device switch to a cellular (metered) connection:

```
// Create a Constraints object that defines when the task should run
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED)
        .build()
```

[WorkManager guide covers WorkRequests with constraints](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work).

Comment: This doesn't really work because cellular networks can be unmetered and WiFi networks can be metered. That is why that was deprecated in the [JobScheduler API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#NETWORK_TYPE_METERED).

Comment: Interesting, I always assumed that Metered ~ Cellular.

You can open a feature request on the WorkManager issue tracker but there's nothing in WorkManager at this moment to specify the Network Transport type: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197